# Jquery get closest a href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below markup and I am trying to get the href but always getting undefined.  Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="mixSpanLeft" style="background-image: url(http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/29/20/3HE5Mx.jpg)">
        <a href="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/29/20/3HE5Mx.jpg"></a>
    </span>
    <div class="mixDivRight">
        <p class="bottomP"><button>Select</button><p>
    </div>
</div>

$container = $('.wrapper');
$container.on('click', '.bottomP', function (event) {
    console.log($(this).closest('a').attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: You havn't id `wrapper` in document. You should use `.wrapper` instead.

Comment: Also, the anchor isn't an ancestor of `.bottomP`, so closest won't work

Comment: Ugh! Yes, thank you Mohammed.  and Evolution that is correct.  ancestor, ugh!  I spent 2 hrs trying this.  haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you fix the class/ID issue noted in the comments by Mohammad you could use:

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.bottomP', function (event) {
    console.log($(this).closest('.wrapper').find('a').attr('href'));
});
```

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.bottomP', function (event) {
    console.log($(this).closest('.wrapper').find('a').attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="mixSpanLeft" style="background-image: url(http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/29/20/3HE5Mx.jpg)">
        <a href="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/29/20/3HE5Mx.jpg"></a>
    </span>
    <div class="mixDivRight">
        <p class="bottomP"><button>Select</button><p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  With those changes it works.  Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what Mohammad mentioned about needing to use .wrapper instead of #wrapper. I recommend using `.find()` instead of `.closest()`. `.closest()` does not work in IE, but that might not be an issue for you. you can also do something like this:

```
$("div.wrapper").on('click', '.bottomP', function () {
    console.log($("div.wrapper a:first").attr('href'));
});
```

This will grab the first `<a>` tag inside the wrapper div.